# Laravel, Vue refresh order after axios

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have problem with refreshing data afer done axios method. I have statuses to change. When someone change status I want to have only status name without buttons, but when I do this, order is not refreshing, It works only when I go somewere else and go back to this site, then actual order is load, button is gone and everything works. How to do, that when someone change styatus, then new order i load and button is gone at the same time?

Here is my code:

```
 <div v-if="(order.order_products[key].statuses[0].id) == 4 && orderLastStatus != 3">
                    <div  v-for="status in availableStatuses">
                        <button v-on:click="changeProductStatus(order_product.id, status.id)"
                                v-bind:value="status.id"
                        >{{status.name}}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div v-else>
                    {{order.order_products[key].statuses[0].name}}
                </div>
```

And Vue:

```
  changeProductStatus: function (orderProductId, statusId) {
            var self = this;
            if (confirm("Are you sure You want to change status?")) {
                axios.post("/order/" + orderProductId + "/changeStatus",
                    {"status_id": statusId})
                    .then(function (response) {        
                        self.selected[orderProductId] = statusId;
                        console.log(self.selected);
                    })
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [array change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

So in you success call back of the axios request do it like this:

```
self.$set(self.selected, orderProductId, statusId);
```

Instead of

```
self.selected[orderProductId] = statusId;
```

Comment: It works but It doesn't refresh me my whole order and still have to refresh site to have changes statuses. Is it possible to change status and at the same time refresh whole statuses and see changed stataus without refreshing site?

Comment: @wenus move your `v-for` loop to the outer most div not the button

Comment: Ok I changed it

Comment: Nope... I'm trying to change last status for product. My buttons are changing buttons but problem is that it doesn't change dynamically and I have to refresh site to see that buttons are gone, I would like to be gone them just after change stataus

Comment: @wenus can you produce a fiddle so that it can be debugged easily...cause what i said should work as `$set` changes the data in a reactive way

Comment: It's hard to write because I have a lot of code :P The problem is because my last status of product is not changing dynamically here : <div v-if="(order.order_products[key].statuses[0].id) == 4 && orderLastStatus != 3">